# Change color of the text in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/j4dcbovo/2/)

I have a contenteditable div. I want the functionality in the div as follows:

When I click on red anchor tag, the new text that I will write will be of red color, and when clicked blue, the text should start writing with  blue color.
Note: When click on the blue color anchor, the content written in red color should not get blue and vice versa. This means that in the div, we will have text written in red and blue color at last. I can write text anywhere in the div.

```
$("#red").click(function () {
    $("div").addClass("red");
    $("div").removeClass("blue");
});

$("#blue").click(function () {
    $("div").addClass("blue");
    $("div").removeClass("red");
});
```

Problem: The problem in my code is that when i click on red, it changes all the color of the div in red and same as of blue.

Comment: You need to create a new span element at the cursor position and add a class to it. This might help: http://plugins.jquery.com/caret/

Comment: Yes, i know it and I m working on it but not able to implement it. @ManojKumar

Comment: The link you gave doesnot work @ManojKumar

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/acdvorak/jquery.caret

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31583680/4763793

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could make use of HTML editing APIs for such use-cases. Reference here: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html

In short, use the `execCommand` along with `styleWithCSS` to achieve what you want. `styleWithCSS` will let you control whether CSS or HTML formatting should be generated by the execCommand method into the document. Pass `true` to use the CSS styling instead of generating the font tag.

Try it out below...

***Example Snippet***:

```js
var 
    red = document.getElementById("red"),
    blue = document.getElementById("blue"),
    reset = document.getElementById("reset")
;

red.addEventListener("click", function() { setColor("#f00"); });
blue.addEventListener("click", function() { setColor("#00f"); });
reset.addEventListener("click", function() { setColor("#000"); });

function setColor(color) {
    document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="red">Red</a> | <a href="#" id="blue">Blue</a> | <a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a> | 
<p contentEditable="true" id="ce">this is some text</p>
```

This will generate HTML with CSS applied, like this:

```
<p contenteditable="true">
    this is <span style="color: #f00;">some</span> text
</p>
```

Hope that helps.

.

Comment: Much better answer than mine...Great work... Coudn't resist upvoting .. +1 added :)

Comment: Thanks buddy. That helped a lot :-) @Abhitalks

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
$("#red,#blue").click(function () {
    $new = $("<div>", {
            class: $(this).attr('id'), 
            contenteditable : 'true'
        })
    $("#my-contenteditable-div")
        .append($new)
        .children('div:last').focus();
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/j4dcbovo/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I tired. I am not sure as to what you are trying to achieve.

What I did:
1. What I did is created editable span with red and blue colour when the button was clicked.
2. negative margin for span to reduce the space created by '`&nbsp;`'

Check the code. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/thomas014/9u7o8oLc/)

```js
$("#red").click(function () {
       $('<span>')                      
        .attr('contenteditable','true') 
       .attr('class','red') 
        .html('&nbsp;')        
        .appendTo('#my-contenteditable-div')   
});

$("#blue").click(function () {
   $('<span>')                      
        .attr('contenteditable','true') 
       .attr('class','blue') 
        .html('&nbsp;')        
        .appendTo('#my-contenteditable-div')   
});
```

```css
.red
{
    color:red;
}
.blue
{
    color:blue;
}
div
{
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
span{margin-left:-4px;}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="red">Red Pen</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="blue">Blue Pen</a><br/><br/><br/>
<div contenteditable="true" id="my-contenteditable-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It works perfectly for me

```
$("#red").click(function () {
$('#my-contenteditable-div').html($('#my-contenteditable-div').html() + '<span class="red">&nbsp;');
});

$("#blue").click(function () {
$('#my-contenteditable-div').html($('#my-contenteditable-div').html() + '<span class="blue">&nbsp;');
});
```

Demo Here :  https://jsfiddle.net/Saneesharoor/ftwbx88p/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
$("#red").click(function () {
    $("div").html($("div").html() + "<span style='color:red'></span>");
});

$("#blue").click(function () {
    $("div").html($("div").html() + "<span style='color:blue'></span>");
});

$("div").keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div > span:last-child").text($("div > span:last-child").text() + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qysa11w/)